Independence of generalized coordinates
In double pendulum when θ1 (the upper angle with vertical) changes it causes an eminent change on θ2(the lower one) which implies that they are not independent how can they still choosen for generalized coordinates.

During the (generally chaotic) motion, is any value for $\theta_2$ possible for an arbitrary $\theta_1$?
